# Make ListView FindItemWithText match entire text

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a `ListView` with two columns, and before enter a new item in the listview, I want to prevent entering a duplicate value, so I found `ListView.FindItemWithText` to accomplish that.

But I realized that if I enter `232323`, and then enter `2323`, which is different but starts with the same digits as the first entry, the function returns that item as a match.

I wonder if there is any way to match the whole text (exact text) to avoid the above.

Here is my code:

```
Dim ChkSIM As New ListViewItem
ChkSIM = lvItems.FindItemWithText("2323")
If Not ChkSIM Is Nothing Then
     lblErrorSIM.Text = "Already in list"
End If
```

Comment: Code tip: `If Not x Is Nothing` → `If x IsNot Nothing`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ListView.FindItemWithText` has an overload to find only exact matches:

```
Dim ChkSIM As ListViewItem = lvItems.FindItemWithText("2323", True, 0, False)
```

For more information, see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x03e4732.aspx).